# SQL query INSERT not working inserting values into my DB

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm trying to insert registration data into a database but my php code isn't inserting the values into the DB although I'm not getting any errors either, can someone help me? this is the code i'm currently using:

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","myusername","mypassword");
mysql_select_db("application");

$queryreg = mysql_query('INSERT INTO users("username","password","email","date") VALUES("$username","$password","$email","$date")');

die ("You Have Been Registered.");
```

I just need to add the **username password email and date** into the fields i have specified but it won't work, please someone help!

Comment: In PHP, variables don't get resolved in single quote strings.  They do in double quote strings.  So as noted below, you can do it with single quotes and . operators, or do it with double quotes and escape all quotes within your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change  this line

```
 $queryreg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(username,password,email,date)
 VALUES('".$username."','".$password."','".$email."','".$date."')");
```

check error

```
if (mysql_errno()) { 
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: I've done that but it still isn't inserting the data into the DB ):

Comment: Yeah ;o "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Comment: The fields in my database are "id username password email joined admin vip" if that helped

Comment: in the table users, do you have more fields , mandatory (could not be null)

Comment: can you publish the create table

Comment: Yup, I posted them just before you commented :), thanks for this btw it's appreciaited :)

Comment: you dont have a date field ! in the query you put date field , why ?

Comment: Oh my :|, noob mistake, I put date instead of joined :/

Comment: Indeed :), thank you for all your help man, it's really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good reference for connecting and doing an insert into a database using PHP and MySQL [W3Schools PHP MySQL Insert](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_insert.asp). From the looks of it you need to remove the "s around username, password, email and date like Haim Evgi mentioned. Also I would try closing the connection if you are finished with it. Here is a code sample from the site:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES ('Peter', 'Griffin', '35')");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) 
VALUES ('Glenn', 'Quagmire', '33')");

mysql_close($con);
```